# How to open different URLs by different buttons?

Tags: javascript, html

This is my HTML and JavaScript code

```
<input type="text" id="text" /> 
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Submit" onClick="javascript: window.open('http://example.com/' + document.getElementById('text').value);" />
```

If you input `anytext` in the form box and click on the **Submit button**, it will open: `http://example.com/anytext`.

I want to add three buttons named `page1` `page2` and `page3` under the form. If I click on the button `page1` and click on submit button, it will open:  `http://example.com/page1/anytext`

How can I do it?

Comment: what do you want to do with the buttons? post the form on that url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**hope this works for you**

```
<input id="text" type="text" name="text">
<input type="button" name="page1" onclick="javascript:window.open('http://example.com/' + this.name + '/' + document.getElementById('text').value)" value="page1">
<input type="button" name="page2" onclick="javascript:window.open('http://example.com/' + this.name + '/' + document.getElementById('text').value)" value="page2">
<input type="button" name="page3" onclick="javascript:window.open('http://example.com/' + this.name + '/' + document.getElementById('text').value)" value="page3">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `select`:

```html
<input type="text" id="text" /> 

<select id="page" size="1">
  <option value="page1">Page 1</option>
  <option value="page2">Page 2</option>
  <option value="page3">Page 3</option>
</select>

<input type="button" id="btn" value="Submit" onClick="javascript: alert('http://example.com/' + 
document.getElementById('page').options[document.getElementById('page').selectedIndex].value + '/' + document.getElementById('text').value);" />
```